# Java Multi-threaded Server with Array Programming

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, distributed-computing

I am a new in distributed computing in Java. I came across a problem when I try to create a server with multi-threads that connects with clients.

The clients will calculate a Pi value using the random generator and then send its result to the server and the server will collect the incoming value and calculate and display the average.

I expect the clients to calculate pi. and send it to server. The server would collect each pi result and calculate & display it on the screen. For example, client 1 calculated value is 3.141, client 2 calculated value is 3.143, and then the server would connect each thread and display 3.142.

It does not come through the result. I don't know what's my problem. It seems that I got a problem in constructing my thread. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

The following is my code:

**Server Code:**

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final int size = 5; //4, 5, 6, etc.
    double sum = 0;
    final int PORT = 1234;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    MyThread[] a = new MyThread[size];
    Thread[] t = new Thread[size];

    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      a[i] = new MyThread(serverSocket.accept());
      System.out.println("server is ready...");
      t[i] = new Thread(a);
      t[i].start();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      try {
        t[i].join();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      sum += a[i].getValue();
    }
    System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / size);
  }
}
```

**Thread Code:**

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
  private double value = 0;
  public double getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  Socket socket;
  MyThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      String message = null;
      BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      while ((message = buff.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Incoming client message: " + message);
        value = Double.parseDouble(message);
      }
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    long toss, number_of_tosses, number_in_circle = 0;
    double x, y, distance_squared, pi_estimate;
    Random generator = new Random();
    number_of_tosses = generator.nextInt(5000) + 5000;
    for (toss = 0; toss < number_of_tosses; toss++) {
      x = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
      y = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
      distance_squared = x * x + y * y;
      if (distance_squared <= 1) number_in_circle++;
    }
    pi_estimate = 4 * number_in_circle / ((double) number_of_tosses);
    printWriter.println(pi_estimate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide any exceptions you are getting and the result.

Comment: I thought if I modify the t[i] = new Thread(a) into t[i] = new Thread(a[i]), the problem would be solved, right?

Comment: That should be the proper way to create your custom thread, yes. But I am still not sure if you are getting any exceptions or others.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PrintWriter it is advisable to call the flush() method afterwards.
Like this:`

```
 try{
   Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
   writer.println("message");
   writer.flush(); // In your case: printWriter.flush();

 catch(IOException exception) {
       exception.printStackTrace();
 }
```